# Expectation of $\frac{1-\Phi(\frac{Y-\mu_z}{\sigma_z}-\sigma_z)}{1-\Phi(\frac{Y-\mu_z}{\sigma_z})}$ of normal random variable.

Tags: probability-distributions

The question is:

Suppose that X and Y are independent Normally distributed random variables,
$$X\sim N(a,\sigma_1^2)$$
$$Y\sim N(b,\sigma_2^2)$$
and $Z = \rho X + \sqrt{(1-\rho^2)}Y$, find $E[max(0,e^Z-e^Y)]$.

My solution is as follows:
$(Z,Y)$ has joint normal distribution:
$$\mu_Z = \rho a + \sqrt{1-\rho^2}b$$
$$\sigma_Z^2 = \rho^2\sigma_1^2 + (1-\rho^2)\sigma_2^2$$
$$\mu_Y = b$$
$$\sigma_Y^2 = \sigma_2^2$$
$$cov(Z,Y) = \sqrt{1-\rho^2}\sigma_2^2$$

the desired expectation can be written as:
$$E[max(0,e^Z-e^Y)] = E[e^Z 1_{Z\geq Y}] - E[e^Y 1_{Z\geq Y}]$$
to compute $E[e^Z 1_{Z\geq Y}]$, I use the density of truncated normal distribution:
$$P(Z\leq z|Z\geq y) = E[1_{Z\leq z}|1_{Z\geq y}] = \frac{E[1_{Z\leq z}1_{Z\geq y}]}{P(Z\geq y)}$$ 
$$P(Z\leq z|Z\geq y) = \frac{\Phi(\frac{z-\mu_Z}{\sigma_Z})-\Phi(\frac{y-\mu_Z}{\sigma_Z})}{1-\Phi(\frac{y-\mu_Z}{\sigma_Z})}$$
take derivative with respect of z, we have distribution density function on $z\in [y,+\infty)$:
$$f_{Z|Z\geq y}(z) = \frac{\frac{1}{\sigma_Z}\phi(\frac{z-\mu_Z}{\sigma_Z})}{1-\Phi(\frac{y-\mu_Z}{\sigma_Z})}$$
Then
$$E[e^Z 1_{Z\geq Y}] = E[E[e^Z|1_{Z\geq Y},Y]] = \int_{\infty}^{-\infty}\int_{y}^{\infty}e^z \frac{\frac{1}{\sigma_Z}\phi(\frac{z-\mu_Z}{\sigma_Z})}{1-\Phi(\frac{y-\mu_Z}{\sigma_Z})} dz \phi(y) dy$$
$$= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1-\Phi(\frac{y-\mu_Z}{\sigma_Z}-\sigma_Z)}{1-\Phi(\frac{y-\mu_Z}{\sigma_Z})}\phi(y)dy$$

This is where I got stuck.

I have not try the approach to use the joint distribution of $(Y,Z)$ to directly compute $E[e^Z 1_{Z\geq Y}]$.

Thank you for your answers.